# Find dropdown-item from generated bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically generated bootstrap **.dropdown-menu** and I cannot target the **.dropdown-item** child class.

I want to be able to toggle a class on each specific **.dropdown-item** when a user clicks on it.

The html looks like this after is dynamically generated:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
 <label class="dropdown-item">
  <input type="checkbox" data-field="name" value="1" checked="checked">
  <span>name</span>
 </label>

 <label class="dropdown-item">
  <input type="checkbox" data-field="price" value="2" checked="checked">
  <span>price</span>
 </label>

 <label class="dropdown-item">
  <input type="checkbox" data-field="column1" value="3" checked="checked">
  <span>column 1</span>
 </label>
</div>
```

I have tried targeting it directly with:

```
$(".dropdown-item").click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("item-selected");
});
```

but it doesn't work.

I read in an answer here: [jquery selecting dynamic class id inside dynamically created div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684133/jquery-selecting-dynamic-class-id-inside-dynamically-created-div), that I needed to delegate with newly created elements and so I am able to target the dynamically generated **.dropdown-menu** with:

```
$(document).on('change',"[class*=dropdown-menu]", function() {
 alert("You clicked on a .dropmenu-item!");
 $(this).children(".dropdown-item").toggleClass("item-selected");
});
```

Clicking on each **.dropdown-item** toggles the class on all items.

I would like to only toggle the class on the specific **.dropdown-item** the user is clicking on

https://codepen.io/makloon/pen/mdboxEb

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Initialize all to selected, since that's the default state.
$('.dropdown-item').addClass('item-selected');

// Use `mousedown` since Bootstrap Tables prevents propagation of `click`.
$('.dropdown-item').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  // This runs _before_ the checkbox is checked/unchecked.
  if ($(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).removeClass("item-selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("item-selected");
  }
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/mac9416/pen/yLBwKKv

The problem is that Bootstrap Tables prevents propagation of the `click` event. So we have to listen for an event that happens earlier - namely, `mousedown`.

And instead of using `toggleClass`, I've set it up to explicitly use the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot to mention that I did try that to no avail. It doesnt find the **.dropdown-item** class.

Comment: Can you set up a minimal reproduction of the problem on something like codepen?

Comment: @MarcusWallace updated with example, and maybe a way to solve a second bug.

Comment: @MarcusWallace I think Bootstrap Tables is stopping the event from bubbling up... I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: It works on the 3 checkboxes generated by your suggestion but not on the ones generated by the Bootstrap Tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199971/discussion-between-michael-crenshaw-and-marcus-wallace).

Comment: Success! I just had to invert the background color on the .dropdown-item classes to suit my needs. I works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcusWallace you bet! I noticed some states where a mousedown won’t result in a checkbox state change. That may require a setTimeout to resolve. The ideal solution would be for Bootstrap Tables to fire an afterChange event (since it’s hiding the input’s change event). Then you could just loop over the items and set the appropriate classes.